# Create Water In Libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

I am develooping a game in libgdx with box2d.
I spent hours of searching for a tutorial or somthing that explain how to create water in libgdx with box2d. I can't find how to do this. If somone have an idea it will very help me.

How to create water in libgdx with box2d?

I am really need your help.

Comment: water, like buoyancy or a water texture effect?

Comment: Just create a sensor fixture and whenever a body collides with this fixture, you will apply a force in the opposite direction of gravity.

Comment: Good tut http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/buoyancy

Comment: This also explains how you can make splash and also water in your game: http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/make-a-splash-with-dynamic-2d-water-effects--gamedev-236

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [this libgdx/box2d android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.leakedbits.codelabs), run it and then choose "Buoyancy" to see if that is what you are looking for. It is open source and the link for its github is in the app's description.

If you prefer, here is directly to their Buoyancy test class:
https://github.com/Leakedbits/Codelabs/blob/master/codelabs/src/com/leakedbits/codelabs/box2d/BuoyancySample.java

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try Google's liquidfun [Liquidfun](http://google.github.io/liquidfun/) integration with libgdx.
liquidfun is an extension to box2D. So it has additional functionality to create particle groups that behaves like liquids.
I successfully tried this [libgdx liquidfun extension](https://github.com/finnstr/gdx-liquidfun-extension/wiki/Setup) in a sample libgdx project.